# Rest Service URL giving Not working and giving Error

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs

So I have been trying to make this rest service work and I have been on it for a few days but just can't get the URL to work no matter what I try. I first tried every suggestion the internet gave regarding to the web.xml file. Once I realised it's a last cause I tried the JAXRSConfiguration class with an '@ApplicationPath("/")' annotation.

### So here is the JAXRS Class:

```
    @ApplicationPath("api")
    public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

        public JAXRSConfiguration() {
            BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
            beanConfig.setVersion("2.0.0");
            beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
            beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
            beanConfig.setBasePath("/MyApp/api");
            beanConfig.setResourcePackage("rest");
            beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
            beanConfig.setScan();
            getClasses();
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
            classes.add(UserResource.class);
            classes.add(MessageService.class);
            return classes;
        }
    }
```

### And here is one of my resource files:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {
    private UserService service = new UserService();

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public void deleteMessage(@PathParam("userId") int id) {
        service.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{userId}/follow/{userToFollowId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void followUser(@PathParam("userToFollowId") int userId, int userToFollowId) {
        service.followUser(userId, userToFollowId);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User registerUser(User user) {
        return service.registerUser(user);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public User updateUser(User user) {
        return service.updateUser(user);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public User getUser(@PathParam("userId") int id) {
        return service.getUser(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return service.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}/followers")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getFollowers(@PathParam("userId") int id) {
        return service.getFollowers(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}/followings")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getFollowings(@PathParam("userId") int id) {
        return service.getFollowings(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}/kweets")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Kweet> getKweets(@PathParam("userId") String username) {
        return service.getKweets(username);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}/timeline")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Kweet> loadTimeline(@PathParam("userId") int id) {
        return service.loadTimeline(id);
    }
}
```

### The Error I'm getting is:

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0

Comment: This is very broad. Maybe you should also post the web.xml file, if any. Or your application package structure.

Comment: Which URL are you trying?

Comment: Here is my package structure: https://gyazo.com/781ebbaf357779cd3ac800e6d84f2d60

Comment: I am using the url: localhost:8080/KwetterApp I also tried like localhost:8080/KwetterApp_war_exploded but nothing works.

Comment: See answer. I suppose you're trying to boot it using IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your IDEA module settings, and look under *Artifacts*. You'll find something like this

[image]

The highlighted name of the `war`/exploded artifact is going to be your server *context path*.
In my case it would become

```
http://localhost:8080/kwetter-0.0.1
```

You should replace it with yours.
Now, you need to add the `@ApplicationPath` path, which is `/api`. So it becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/kwetter-0.0.1/api
```

Now, you need to add the REST service `@Path`, which is `/users`. So it becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/kwetter-0.0.1/api/users
```

An example:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/kwetter-0.0.1/api/users/{userId}/followers
```

---

Be sure you don't have this checked, under *Run/Debug* configuration.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190137/discussion-on-answer-by-lppedd-rest-service-url-giving-not-working-and-giving-er).